# Toolbar is not showing in Blazor wrapper for Apexchart

Tags: blazor, apexcharts

I have tried to build a bar chart using apex charts with Blazor. this is the GitHub repo that I have used to build this([enter link description here](https://github.com/apexcharts/Blazor-ApexCharts))

using this link([enter link description here](https://apexcharts.github.io/Blazor-ApexCharts/)) we can see a live demo on this site.

this is my apex chart component

```
<ApexChart @ref=_detailsChart TItem="LocationViseStockResponse"
                                    Title="Stocks"
                                    OnDataPointSelection=DataPointsSelected
                                    Height=500
                                    Debug>

                                <ApexPointSeries TItem="LocationViseStockResponse"
                                     Items="chartDetails"
                                     Name="Stocks"
                                     SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar" 
                                     XValue="@(e => e.Location.CodeName)"
                                     YValue="@(e => e.Qty)"
                                     OrderByDescending="e=>e.X"/>

                    </ApexChart>
```

everything is working fine.but I need to add a toolbar for this apex chart component with the options like zoom in,zoom out,etc.do I need to pass parameter or whatever thing to do this . anybody who knows this, please help me, how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

For bar charts you will have to set the XAxisTickPlacement to "on" in order to enable zoom

```
options.Xaxis = new XAxis { TickPlacement = "on" };
```

More info, https://apexcharts.com/docs/zooming-in-category-x-axis/